# iOS $(document).on() works inside modal, $('').click(function() inside the site only

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have a JS script that I'm using once directly on the site, and once inside a modal. Now I have the iOS-problem that the function

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-level', function(ev) {})
```

only works inside the modal, but not directly on the site. If I'm using this:

```
 $('.btn-level').click(function(ev) {})
```

It works on the site but not on the modal.

How can I write it so that it works in both contexts?

Comment: This is not enough information to figure out what your problem is. Based on what you've posted it seems that your code should work. Can you provide us with a snippet that reproduces the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major difference between the two expressions you posted.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-level', function(ev) {})
```

binds on `$(document)`. On any `click` event inside `$(document)`, if `ev.target` matches `.btn-level` selector, the code is executed. This means that your code will be executed even when you click on buttons that ***were not present in DOM at the time you did the binding***.

The second syntax,

```
$('.btn-level').click(function(ev) {})
```

... binds one event to each `$('.btn-level')` existing in DOM when you are running the binding function. This means that if you create more such buttons or bring them using `$.ajax()`, they will not have any event bound to them.

This is why you should stick to first syntax, if you want your event to work on your all your DOM elements, including the ones that are not currently present in DOM.

---

Another rather important note is that `click` events are ignored by some versions of Safari if:

- the element is an `input[type="hidden"]`
- the element does not have `cursor:pointer`

In order to fix this, you probably want to set

```
.btn-level { cursor:pointer; }
```

in your CSS and, if hidden input, change it to any other type and hide it using `visibility`.